# How to use emmet in VS2015 CSS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have installed web essentials and all plugins.  It lets me use emmet in my views but in scss & css files the normal intellisense still kicks in and it doesn't let me use the emmet shortcodes.

How do I enable it for CSS also?